# Haskell error making a function to determine if a date entered is Valid

Tags: haskell

here's what i tried to use

```
validDate :: Int -> Int -> Bool
validDate d m
  | d <= 31 && m elem highMonths = True
  | d <= 30 && m elem lowMonths = True
  | d <= 28 && m == 2 = True
  | otherwise = False
  where
    highMonths = [1, 3, 5 , 7, 8, 10, 12]
    lowMonths = [4, 6, 9, 11]
```

but its throwing me an error i don't quite understand.

```
WS1.hs:73:22:
Couldn't match expected type ‘(a0 -> [a0] -> Bool) -> [t1] -> Bool’
with actual type ‘Int’
Relevant bindings include highMonths :: [t1] (bound at WS1.hs:78:9)
The function ‘m’ is applied to two arguments,
but its type ‘Int’ has none
In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘m elem highMonths’
In the expression: d <= 31 && m elem highMonths
```

I don't know where I've gone wrong, any help appreciated.

Comment: A major hint lies in this part of the message, I think: "The function ‘m’ is applied to two arguments, but its type ‘Int’ has none [in] ‘m elem highMonths’", which suggests that `elem` isn't the infix form of a function.

Comment: @molbdnilo It suggests that `m` is being treated as a function. This should lead the OP to ask Q: "Why is `m` being treated as a function"? A: because `elem` is *not* being treated as an infix function, otherwise `m` would be treated as an argument to `elem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use infix notation for `elem`:

```
m `elem` lowMonths
```

The [docs for `elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) show that it is *not* an infix function (we know this because it does not have parentheses), so to use it in infix style, you have to surround it by backticks.

Contrast this with [`(!!)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-), which is defined in parentheses. This means it is automatically an infix function, so it can be used between operands without backticks: `xs !! 2`. To make the operator prefix, you can simply wrap it in parentheses: `(!!) xs 2`

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that, I looked through the prelude docs and everything. Thank you.